# Connecting to SQL Server Database via Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Good day, awesome people! I know similar questions have been asked, but I've read through many of them already without success. Here's is my problem:

I've added a data source in Visual Studios 2012 Express (I'm using C#)  connecting to a  database I created in SQL Server Express 2016. When I run my project and attempt executing any code relating to the database, I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)."

I am connecting locally, not remotely.

I have already gone through the following:

- On creating the connection, "Test Connection" is successful.
- I've quadruple-checked my connection string.
- SQL Server is running.
- In SQL Server Management Studio properties, remote connection is enabled (even though I'm not connecting remotely.)
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, under Services, SQL Server is running. Under SQL Server Network Configuration, Shared Memory, Named Pipes and TCP/IP are all enabled.

My connection string:

```
Data Source=name\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=(catalog name);Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: Can you connect to the same instance using SSMS? With exactly the data source you have in the connection string and the same user and password?

Comment: Hi. Yes, that works fine.

Comment: @mason Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: Is `(source name)` the actual name? Most likely, your source should be `computername\instancename` as the `Data Source`.

Comment: No, it isn't. The actual name is identical to that of the connection in SSMS. Like I said, when I created the connection in VS, I tested it and it was successful. I used the same string given in the wizard

Comment: in source name try to write complete name "<SERVER>\<instance_name>". 
You can test you connection using .udl file. 
to create a .udl file, create a .txt file in desktop pc and change extension to .udl, then open it! and configure to connect. If you open .udl file with notepad when connection is working, you got the connection string.

Comment: @M56 it is <computername>\SQLExpress. If I get the error "File cannot be opened. Ensure it is a valid Data Link file" when trying to open the .udl file, does that mean the connection string is wrong? This is new to me :)

Comment: @Nazgul no, [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/) you have a detail to use .udl file.

Comment: @M56, thanks, the linked helped. I added the source name, hit Test Connection, and it was successful.

Comment: Now use that connection string in your app and test! ;)

Comment: @M56 I'm afraid I still get the error. :/

Comment: If I originally started coding in VS 2012 Ultimate, then continued to 2012 Express, could it cause this problem?

Comment: @Nazgul try to add again (from the begin) the data source (or add another datasource with other name but to same db). Maybe some reference is corrupted...

Comment: @M56 I'd already tried that a few times; also readding references. I'm going to try reinstalling SQL Server now.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to open the SQL port on the firewall 1433.

Comment: Disabling the firewall should do it. You might try putting the port number in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable *SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode* in Server Properties > Security > Server Authentication (via SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: What about remote connection?

Comment: @PawelKucharski I'm not connecting remotely. Nevertheless, I have tried enabling it to no avail.